# UItableViewCells Are Repeating

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

Ok guys I created a Simple table View with a radio Button in each cell, This is done in order to see why the cells are repeating.  I set my Rows to a ridiculously high count to show that the cells indeed do repeat. The goal of this simple project is to come to a sound Conclusion in resolving this issue since there are several post on this topic none in which give a correct result.  When a user selects a button in the cell  that cell and only that cell should be Affected.  Here is the code in its entirety .

```
    #import "faQViewController.h"

     @interface faQViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation faQViewController
    @synthesize button1,button2;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

     - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
     [super viewDidUnload];
     // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
     if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 30;


    }


    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"cell";
    button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 32);
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell ==nil) {        
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                 ] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
         [cell.contentView
          addSubview:button1];
    }

   // cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOff.png"];


    return cell;
}

    -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    if ([sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal ]== [UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOff.png"]){
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {

        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Cells do not repeat in tableViews, you are reusing cells.

Comment: What did you think the word 'Reusable' meant in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: its not my first dance with tableViews, and from the looks of it the cells are being reused, The problem is this, say i have an editable object in a cell i.e an image of a button. If the user changes this editable object i.e  an image why does the cell reload itself and remove the edited image when the user scrolls out of view. And what is the solution for it not to change.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the cells, thus you see the same cells come up for other rows if you do not change the content. Since you only set the content when you allocate the cell, the content will stay the same when the cell is reused

so

```
  //Here you tell the tableView to re use a cell if one is available for reuse
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   //if the cell is nil (none available for reuse)
    if (cell ==nil) {        
        //you create the cell and set its content
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                 ] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
         [cell.contentView
          addSubview:button1];
    }
    //return the cell
   return cell;
```

If you want to change the cells content depending on the row you should do so after your cell==nil block so

```
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       //if the cell is nil (none available for reuse)
        if (cell ==nil) {        
            //you create the cell and set its content
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                     ] autorelease];
            }

          //set the content
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
             [cell.contentView
              addSubview:button1];

        //return the cell
       return cell;
```

hope this helps..

Comment: This however reloads the image, so when the user clicks the button image to change the image, it reverts back to the original once you scroll down out of view

Answer (score 1):

Daniels answer helped me clear somethings up to solve my issue. My issue is i was seeing `sections 0,1,2` were being created uniquely but then `second 3` was being generated the same as `section 0`, here is my set up:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    CustomCell* cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SECTION %d", indexPath.section]];

    NSLog(@"SECTION %d", indexPath.section);

    return cell;
}
```

What I needed to change was the `cellIndentifier` since I was setting them all to the same ID:

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell-%d", indexPath.section];
```